# Why does Windows not see python.exe?

Tags: python, anaconda

> **Update 3:** Found it - it's a "helpful" feature of Windows to go find apps via the Windows store ([details here](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor)).

I installed Anaconda (following a Udacity course) and am trying to get it set up right to run on Windows. The Udacity course assumes I have Git Bash (I don't) and so it's not much help.

I added the following to the path:

- C:\Users\david\anaconda3
- C:\Users\david\anaconda3\Scripts

When I run "conda --version" I get the expected version number. But when I run "python --version" I get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>python --version
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>
```

When I run "path", it is there:

```
... 
Studio\bin;C:\Users\david\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\david\anaconda3;C:\Users\david\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1.2\bin;;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual St
...
```

And explicitly setting the location of python.exe works:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>\users\david\anaconda3\python --version
Python 3.8.8

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>
```

So why does it not find it when I just run python?

**Update:**
Yes I opened a new command window after saving the additions to the path (always a good question to ask though).

For running where:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>where python
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\david\anaconda3\python.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>
```

So it finds it under where, but not when trying to run it.

**Update 2:**
Is it possible that Windows does not want to run apps under the c:\users folder for security reasons? It's an unusualy place to put a .exe.

Comment: Try running `where python` and see if that's in your path too.

Comment: Did you open a new cmd after adding python to path ?

Comment: @not_speshal where finds it (added result above), but it doesn't find "python".

Comment: @not_speshal I just searched in the add/removes applications. The only hit for python is anaconda. And I don't recall earlier installing python. Could it just be part of Windows?

Comment: I doubt it - I had a local installation of Python that was interfering with Anaconda too. Probably not recommended, but I just deleted that folder. If you choose to do this, please make sure you have a backup in case it breaks something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a guess since you haven't provided the full value of your PATH variable, but I think the entry for your Anaconda folder occurs after the entry for `<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` so it gets hidden.

Windows searches the folders in PATH in order and executes the first `python.exe` file that it finds, which in this case is the message saying to download Python from the Store.

Try making `\users\david\anaconda3\` as the first value in your PATH value.

Comment: Thank you - great guess with incomplete information that was exactly right. Brilliant.

Comment: @DavidThielen Glad I could help, I've spent much more time than I'd like to admit before on the same problem :)